# Angulars $httpBackend not pure unit testing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

Angular advocates the use of [$httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend) to test your service. Doesn't that break the principle of unit testing since it also tests angular internals?

Shouldn't we rather test with a mocked $resource (or $http if that's what you use)?

Is this just for convenience?

Comment: You're not *testing* Angular internals, you're *using* Angular internals. It *is* a mocked resource. You want to use your own?

Comment: Well if I understand correctly the flow is this: myService => $resource => $http => $httpBackend. When I use $httpBackend.expectGET in my tests, the code passes through 2 layers before it hits the mocked $httpBackend. Wouldn't I have then implicitly partially tested both $resource and $http?